# asyncio: корректная остановка не своих сопрограмм

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.x, asyncio

Я опять с той же проблемой. В [предыдущем вопросе](/questions/429692) все таски были под моим контролем, и я мог их вручную закрывать. Но вот беда: мне тут потребовались вебсокеты. В примерах в [документации к одноимённому модулю](https://aaugustin.github.io/websockets/) никакого корректного закрытия не производится:

```
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Я поигрался с примерами, и да, при Ctrl+C ругается, если есть подключенный клиент:

```
$ python websocket_server.py 
^C
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in: Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<run() running at websockets/protocol.py:235> 
  wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>
  cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at asyncio/tasks.py:399]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<get() running at asyncio/queues.py:198> 
  wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>
  cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at asyncio/tasks.py:399]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<handler() running at websockets/server.py:64> 
  wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
```

Так как корректного способа завершения в документации не представлено и быстрое тыкание наличия всяких `server.close()` ни к какому продуктивному результату не привело, снова появляется вопрос о корректном завершении приложения, если таски мной не контролируются.

Это просто эта библиотека кривая? Или это характерно для любых asyncio-библиотек и я чего-то не понимаю в самой сути asyncio и кто-нибудь ткнёт меня а какую-нибудь матчасть по этому поводу?

Как всё-таки корректно завершать всё это дело в общем случае?

---

С общим случаем принцип понятен, но websockets закрываться никак не хочет. Минимальный пример для повторения (на основе ответа @jfs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import asyncio
import websockets


@asyncio.coroutine
def echo(ws, path):
    print('client started')
    while True:
        data = yield from ws.recv()
        if data is None:
            break
        yield from ws.send(data)
    print('client finished')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
start_server = websockets.serve(echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(start_server)

print('Listen')
try:
    server = loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
print('Finished')
```

Достаточно просто подключить к нему любой клиент (хоть из браузера — `ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888/');`) и нажать Ctrl+C — отпечатается приведённая ранее ошибка (правда, уже без KeyboardInterrupt).

Comment: Ох, там gevent на третий питон наконец портировали, значит asyncio фтопку -_-

Comment: я могу [воспроизвести поведение](https://gist.github.com/zed/56f9bd5d33fff51f6820). Можно [открыть баг](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/new), чтобы спросить почему *"Task was destroyed but it is pending!"* появляются не смотря на `.close()`, `.wait_closed()` вызовы.

Comment: @jfs Вот повезло мне натыкаться на баги до того, как я полностью asyncio осознаю :( Что ж, [попробовал создать](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/64) (прошу прощения у всех прочитавших за мой английский, у меня с ним плохо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asyncio` реализует кооперативную многозадачность. Это значит, что `websockets` библиотека должна кооперировать (предоставлять возможность чисто завершить соединения). Был открыт баг на websockets [Review cancellation management](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/59).

Даже для обычных (preemptive) потоков не существует общего решения, которое бы корректно остановило бы потоки вне зависимости от кода, который они исполняют (Java выучила этот урок тяжёлым путём). Безопасным для остановки ресурсом является процесс операционной системы, если нас не волнует потеря данных из-за неочищенного файлового буфера, уведомления другой стороны о прекращении сетевого соединения, завершение транзакции базы данных итд. Если волнует, то процесс также обязан кооперировать, если мы хотим его завершить преждевременно.

Чтобы обработать `Ctrl+C` в Питоне, как обычно нужно поймать `KeyboardInterrupt` или определить свой обработчик для `SIGINT` сигнала. [Пример echo сервера в asyncio документации показывает как это можно сделать (`KeyboardInterrupt` + `wait_closed()`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams):

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = yield from reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

    print("Send: %r" % message)
    writer.write(data)
    yield from writer.drain()

    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until CTRL+c is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

В `gevent` (кооперативная многозадачность) также необходимо `KeyboardInterrtupt` ловить.

Документация [`websockets.server.serve()`](http://aaugustin.github.io/websockets/#websockets.server.serve) явно упоминает:

> `serve()` yields a Server which provides a `close()` method and a `wait_closed()` coroutine to stop serving requests.

то есть для websocket сервера можно точно такой же код использовать для корректной остановки:

```
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Comment: Баг закрыли, а как сервер корректно выключать, никто нигде так и не объяснил. Печальбеда

Comment: @andreymal: что происходит если в Ваш код последний пример (с `.wait_closed()`) добавить?

Comment: а его не к чему добавлять. `start_server` — это уже генератор, у него нет wait_closed. (close, оказывается, есть, но, похоже, какой-то родной генераторный, вряд ли это то)

Comment: @andreymal: `server = loop.run_until_complete(start_server)`

Comment: Ой, тут wait_closed есть, сейчас проверю

Comment: Не помогло. Все три строчки из последнего примера успешно отрабатывают, но потом мне ругаются теми же ошибками, что и в вопросе.

Comment: @andreymal: по-меньшей мере `KeyboardInterrupt` не должно быть видно. Создайте [минимальный, но полный пример кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (вместе [с html, javascript если необходимо](https://gist.github.com/zed/1380305)) и приведите полную ошибку (копи-паст) и шаги (словами), которые к ней привели в вопросе.

Comment: Да, KeyboardInterrupt уже не печатается. Добавил пример