# Как передать сигнал завершения из __main__ в Thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую два потока: первый - слушает WebSocket, второй - запускается лишь разово, для того чтобы подписать приложение на события после старта WebSocket.

```
import aiohttp
import requests
import json
import threading


ws_connected = False


сlass ProcessEvent(object):
    # Some class
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class WSListenerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(listen())

    async def listen():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=ARI_AUTH) as session:
            async with session.ws_connect('ws://localhost/events') as ws:
                ws_connected = True
                async for msg in ws:
                    event = ProcessEvent(msg=msg.data)
                    await event.check() 


class Subscriber(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.resubscribe())

    def resubscribe():
        while not ws_connected:
            pass
        requests.post("http://localhost/something", data="payload=")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        event_listener = WSListenerThread()
        event_listener.start()
        subscriber = Subscriber()
        subscriber.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Pressing \"<CTRL> + <C>\".")  
        # Как отправить сигнал на закрытие WS в потоке event_listener?
        sys.exit(0)
```

Как извне корректно закрыть поток?

Comment: В чём смысл два цикла событий заводить? Связанный вопрос [asyncio: корректная остановка не своих сопрограмм](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433554/23044)

Comment: Работаю с Asterisk REST. DELETE/POST/PUT-запросы нужно слать после подключения к сокету в зависимости от состояния сервера и лишь единожды. На скорую руку - не смог придумать способа сделать это по-другому.
Поэтому, в одном - слушаю сокет и обрабатываю его события, во втором - подписываюсь на нужные зависимости.

Comment: Попробую реализовать как связанном вопросе.